# Build Fails while building for cocos2d-x 3.17 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, build-process

While building the game (cocos2dx- 3.17 on ubuntu 22.04) it fails with below error -

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable bin/New10032024/New10032024
/usr/bin/ld: ../cocos2d/external/linux-specific/fmod/prebuilt/64-bit/libfmod.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 2 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: ../cocos2d/external/linux-specific/fmod/prebuilt/64-bit/libfmod.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 3 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: ../cocos2d/external/linux-specific/fmod/prebuilt/64-bit/libfmod.so: .dynsym local symbol at index 4 (>= sh_info of 2)
/usr/bin/ld: ../cocos2d/external/freetype2/prebuilt/linux/64-bit/libfreetype.a(ftbase.linux64.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/New10032024.dir/build.make:168: bin/New10032024/New10032024] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:523: CMakeFiles/New10032024.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

What shall I do next to resolve this.

Comment: [Searching that error message turns up some leads](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=failed+to+set+dynamic+section+sizes%3A+bad+value&ia=web). What have you tried based on your research of these hits so far?